# Wald $\chi^2$ value for a probit model

Tags: r, regression, chi-squared-test, probit

I have fit a probit model in R. However, in addition to the $z$- and $p$-values, I would like to know the Wald $\chi^2$ values for the individual explanatory variables. How do I obtain / calculate the Wald $\chi^2$ values for parameter estimates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the Wald $\chi^2$ values by squaring the $z$-values.

Comment: +1, you might note that all of the $\chi^2$s will have $1$ degree of freedom.